# Count() and left join problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, left-join

I am trying to join two tables while using the count function to get the number in the right table. I thought this is exactly what the LEFT JOIN was for, but in this case it is not working at all.

Simplified version of problem

**Table 1:**

```
ID   Data
1    Blah 
2    Blaha
3    Blahah
```

**Table 2:**

```
ID  Some Data
1   xxxx
1   xxxx
1   xxxx
1   xxxx
1   xxxx
3   xxxx
3   xxxx
3   xxxx
3   xxxx
3   xxxx
```

The query I am using is:

```
SELECT table1.ID, count(table2.ID) As Count
FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
GROUP BY table1.ID
```

I want to display:

```
ID  Count
1   5
2   0
3   5
```

But all I can display is:

```
ID  Count
1   5
3   5
```

Cheers

Comment: Your query looks fine. Sure you group by `table1.id`?

Comment: Are you sure you used a left, and not an inner, join?

Comment: Your query is giving me the correct results. Are you sure table1 is on the left part of the join?

Comment: your query is working fine.

Comment: You said `simplified query`. Check one more time that you have no limiting where conditions for table2 - this often converts left join into inner one.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot. The real query is much larger and I missed that I was grouping on the "table2.ID" despite selecting the "table1.ID".   This can be closed

Answer (score 2):

Check if `count` for `table2.ID` returns null and return 0 in that case

```
SELECT table1.ID, IFNULL(count(table2.ID), 0) As Count
FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
GROUP BY table1.ID
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say, I've already tried that (isnull ,0) and it still doesn't return

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
SELECT table1.ID, count(coalesce(table2.ID,'Dummy')) As Count
FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
GROUP BY table1.ID
```

Currently what happens with your query is `count(table2.ID)` counts only not null values, To count the null values, I have used the coalesce function, So if the value is null, the function returns the dralult value, ie. `'Dummy'` a random text. You can got `nvl` as well. For a better performance you can go for `coalesce`.

**Above all you can go for** `count(*)`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `count(id)`, it will only count the id's that are not NULL. Try for example the following:

```
SELECT      COUNT(1)
,           COUNT(x.id)
FROM        (
                SELECT      1 id UNION ALL
                SELECT      NULL
            ) x
```

Results in `2, 1`.

So, if you use `COUNT(1)` you will get the expected results. You can also use `coalesce` or `isnull`, but I don't see the point in using a function if you don't really need the result of that function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a join for that. 
The easiest way to achieve the desired result:

```
SELECT table1.ID, 
  (SELECT count(*) FROM table2 WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID) As Counter
FROM table1
```

Assuming the id value in table1 is unique.
If table1.ID is not unique you can just use the DISTINCT Keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.ID, 
  (SELECT count(*) FROM table2 WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID) As Counter
FROM table1
```